# Om Next Tutorial: Correctly calling the get-people function

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om

I'm currently following along the om-next [tutorial](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Components%2C-Identity-%26-Normalization). In the [Adding Reads](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Components%2C-Identity-%26-Normalization#adding-reads) section, there's a function `get-people` is defined. Along with this function, the `init-data` map is defined that contains a list of people.

```
(defn get-people [state key]
  (let [st @state]
    (into [] (map #(get-in st %)) (get st key))))

(def init-data {:list/one
 [{:name "John", :points 0}
  {:name "Mary", :points 0}
  {:name "Bob", :points 0}],
 :list/two
 [{:name "Mary", :points 0, :age 27}
  {:name "Gwen", :points 0} 
  {:name "Jeff", :points 0}]})
```

Here's my attempt to call this function.

```
(get-people (atom init-data) :list/one) ;; => [nil nil nil]
```

As you can see, I simply get back a vector of `nil`s . I don't quite understand how I should call this function. Could somebody help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I figured it out.

`init-data` is not the correct data structure to call `get-people` with. The initial data must first be "reconciled" using Om's `reconciler`. You can find more information regarding the reconciler here in the tutorial's [Normalization](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Components%2C-Identity-%26-Normalization#normalization) section.

Reconciling the `init-data` map and then `deref`ing the data returns this normalized data structure:

```
{:list/one
 [[:person/by-name "John"]
  [:person/by-name "Mary"]
  [:person/by-name "Bob"]],
 :list/two
 [[:person/by-name "Mary"]
  [:person/by-name "Gwen"]
  [:person/by-name "Jeff"]],
 :person/by-name
 {"John" {:name "John", :points 0},
  "Mary" {:name "Mary", :points 0, :age 27},
  "Bob" {:name "Bob", :points 0},
  "Gwen" {:name "Gwen", :points 0},
  "Jeff" {:name "Jeff", :points 0}}}
```

Here is a valid call to the `get-people` function using the reconciled init-data:

```
; reconciled initial data
(def reconciled-data
  {:list/one
   [[:person/by-name "John"]
    [:person/by-name "Mary"]
    [:person/by-name "Bob"]],
   :list/two
   [[:person/by-name "Mary"]
    [:person/by-name "Gwen"]
    [:person/by-name "Jeff"]],
   :person/by-name
   {"John" {:name "John", :points 0},
    "Mary" {:name "Mary", :points 0, :age 27},
    "Bob" {:name "Bob", :points 0},
    "Gwen" {:name "Gwen", :points 0},
    "Jeff" {:name "Jeff", :points 0}}}

; correct function call
(get-people (atom reconciled-data) :list/one)

; returned results
[{:name "John", :points 0}
 {:name "Mary", :points 0, :age 27}
 {:name "Bob", :points 0}]
```

Here's what's happening:

1. First, the function retrieves the value associated with the `:list/one` key. In this case, the value is a vector of paths into a map (each path is itself a vector).
2. Next, map over the paths and call the anonymous function on each vector. One of the calls would look like `(get-in st [:person/by-name "John"])` and return `{:name "John", :points 0}`.
3. Return the results as a vector

If anybody is reading this and wants further clarification, please let me know.